# Output named columns, Regex extractall function is outputing empty

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a table with a single column `fullIden` which contains a string of text. I want to use regular expressions and `extractall` to extract values from this string and output them into individual columns. However, although the table is outputting the right columns, all rows are currently empty.

| fullIden |
| --- |
| ENSAPLP00000008325.2 pep primary_assembly:CAU_duck1.0:1:4776:289936:-1 gene:ENSAPLG00000008650.2 transcript:ENSAPLT00000009001.2 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:SHANK3 description:SH3 and multiple ankyrin repeat domains 3 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:14294] |

Here is the regular expression I am using:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?P<PepID>[^\s]+)\spep'
           + r'primary_assembly:(?P<genome_version>[^:]+):'
           + r'(?P<chromosome>[^:]+):'
           + r'(?P<start>[^:]+):'
           + r'(?P<end>[^:]+):'
           + r'(?P<strand>[^:]+):'
           + r'gene:(?P<gene>[^\s]+)\s+'
           + r'transcript:(?P<transcript>[^\s]+)\s*'
           + r'gene_biotype:(?P<gene_biotype>[^\s]+)\s*'
           + r'transcript_biotype:(?P<transcript_biotype>[^\s]+)\s*'
           + r'gene_symbol:(?P<gene_symbol>[^\s]+)\s*'
           + r'description:(?P<description>[^[]+)\s'
           + r'\[Source:(?P<source>[^;]+);*'
           + r'Acc:(?P<accession>[^]]+)\]*')
```

And here is the code I am using to extract the values and output them into individual columns:

```
df = pd.concat([
    df,
    (
        df.fullIden.str.extractall(p)
          .reset_index('match', drop=True)
    )
], axis=1).fillna('')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: We also need the sample text to verify.

Comment: It's edited, I added the string.

Comment: Your regex is not matching the string you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
p = ( # to be adjusted, if needed
    r'(?P<PepID>[^\s]+)\s*pep:?' 
     '\s*primary_assembly:(?P<genome_version>[^:]+):?'
     '\s*(?P<chromosome>[^:]+):?'
     '\s*(?P<start>[^:]+):?'
     '\s*(?P<end>[^:]+):?'
     '\s*(?P<strand>[^:]+):?'
     '\s*gene:(?P<gene>[^\s]+)\s*:?'
     '\s*transcript:(?P<transcript>[^\s]+):?'
     '\s*gene_biotype:(?P<gene_biotype>[^\s]+):?'
     '\s*transcript_biotype:(?P<transcript_biotype>[^\s]+):?'
     '\s*gene_symbol:(?P<gene_symbol>[^\s]+):?'
     '\s*description:(?P<description>[^[]+)'
     '\s*\[Source:(?P<source>[^;]+);*'
     '\s*Acc:(?P<accession>[^]]+)\]*'
)
            
out = df.join(df["fullIden"].str.extract(p))

#if multiple matches per row, df.join(df["fullIden"].str.extractall(p).droplevel(0))
```

Output :

| fullIden | PepID | genome_version | chromosome | start | end | strand | gene | transcript | gene_biotype | transcript_biotype | gene_symbol | description | source | accession |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENSAPLP00000008325.2 pep primary_assembly:CAU_duck1.0:1:4776:289936:-1 gene:ENSAPLG00000008650.2 transcript:ENSAPLT00000009001.2 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:SHANK3 description:SH3 and multiple ankyrin repeat domains 3 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:14294] | ENSAPLP00000008325.2 | CAU_duck1.0 | 1 | 4776 | 289936 | -1 | ENSAPLG00000008650.2 | ENSAPLT00000009001.2 | protein_coding | protein_coding | SHANK3 | SH3 and multiple ankyrin repeat domains 3 | HGNC Symbol | HGNC:14294 |